# window.open() does not open when clicked more than once in internet explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I am using window.open to open my PDF files. Following is my code.

Reactions of various browsers:

In chrome: First time when I click PDF icon, in new window opens the PDF file. I am not closing the opened PDF. Each time when I click on the same PDF icon again it focuses the same file again

In firefox: First time when I click , new window opens with PDF file(almost same as chrome), but on consequent clicks of the same file without closing the existing PDF, it opens the same file again and again and focus it.

In IE: Here is the major problem. On first click the samething happens as with other browsers but on consequent clicks the opened file is not getting focused and nothing happens at all.

Is there anyway to make IE focus on the same PDF that is opened in new window on consequent clicks? Also is there anyway to make firefox stop opening same file again and again and just focus on existing like in Chrome?

```
function open_page(url, name, features) {
    var win = window.open(url,
                         (name == null ? 'page' : 'test'),
                         (features == null ? 'menubar=1,toolbar=1,scrollbars=1,width=1024,height=768,resizable=1' : features));

    if (win == null) {
        alert('Not open');
    } else {
        document.isUnloading = false;
        console.log("#2");
    }
}
```

Comment: In general you cannot control how browsers show new pages or tabs. It's completely under user control.

Comment: What is purpose of opening `window` having same contents multiple times?

Comment: call `win.focus()`?